# convert java object list into CSV

Tags: java, list, csv, object

I have object list with many values in object which comes from XML source:

```
iit.getHomeCurrency().getPrice().toString()
```

If I put  System.out.println(iit.getHomeCurrency().getPrice().toString());
I get succesfully complete list of objects.

But, when I want to convert this object into CSV, using

```
CSVWriter csvWriter = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter("example.csv"));
csvWriter.writeNext(new String[]{iit.getHomeCurrency().getPrice().toString(),"/n"} 
csvWriter.close();
```

I got only one line in csv file :(

Code:

```
for(int i=0;i<contentElement.size();i++){
            JAXBElement<ListInvoiceType> invoiceTypeElement = (JAXBElement<ListInvoiceType>) contentElement.get(i);
            ListInvoiceType listInvoiceType = invoiceTypeElement.getValue();
            List<InvoiceType> invoiceTypeList = listInvoiceType.getInvoice();
            for(InvoiceType invoiceType:invoiceTypeList ){
                InvoiceHeaderType invoiceHeaderType = invoiceType.getInvoiceHead
er();
                InvoiceDetailType invoiceDetailType = invoiceType.getInvoiceDetail();                       

                InvoiceItemType iit = null;
                InvoiceAdvancePaymentItemType iapit = null;
                for(Serializable s:invoiceDetailType.getContent()){
                    if(s instanceof JAXBElement) {
                        JAXBElement<?> element = (JAXBElement)s;
                        if(element.getValue() instanceof InvoiceItemType){
                            iit = (InvoiceItemType)element.getValue();
                        }
                        else if(element.getValue() instanceof InvoiceAdvancePaymentItemType){
                            iapit = (InvoiceAdvancePaymentItemType)element.getValue();
                        }
                        else{
                            throw new Exception("xx");
                        }
                    }

                    else if(s instanceof String){

                    }
                    else{
                        throw new Exception("xx");
                    }       


                        if(iit!=null){          
                        CSVWriter csvWriter = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter("example.csv"));

                        csvWriter.writeNext(new String[]{iit.getHomeCurrency().getPrice().toString(), iit.getCentre().getIds()  ,invoiceHeaderType.getDate().toString(),invoiceHeaderType.getInvoiceType().value(),"\r\n"});

                        csvWriter.close();
```

What shall I change to make java write every object into new row of csv file?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The main problem seems to be that you open a new file for each iteration of the loop, move

```
CSVWriter csvWriter = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter("example.csv"));
```

to before the `for` loop

```
CSVWriter csvWriter = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter("example.csv"));
for(Serializable s:invoiceDetailType.getContent()){
    if(s instanceof JAXBElement) {
        //... 
    }

   if( iit !=n ull){          
       csvWriter.writeNext(new String[]{iit.getHomeCurrency().getPrice().toString(), iit.getCentre().getIds()  ,invoiceHeaderType.getDate().toString(),invoiceHeaderType.getInvoiceType().value(),"\r\n"});
   }
```

and close the file after the `for` loop

```
} //end for loop

 csvWriter.close();
```

Comment: Thanks Joakim, it helped.
Now I have another simple problem, out of XML it may happen not all the fields are filled. I got null pointer exception in such case.

So I try to fix the problem using :
if(iit.getCentre().getIds()==null)  {iit.getCentre().getIds()="data not filled";}

if object is null, fill text "data not filled" in csv.

But, by such code atempt, I got an error: the left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable.

How could I fix null pointer exception please?

Comment: @bennes You get the error because `getIds()` is a method so you can't assign anything to it. Use a local variable instead in your if and either give it the value of  `getIds` or the string you have and then use that variable in the `writeNext` call. Alternatively change `getIds` to return "data not filled" instead of null

Comment: Hi Joakim, I am sorry for my noob questions :( But when I try:
 String hu = iit.getCentre().getIds().toString();
     if(hu==null)
     {hu= "data not filled" ;}

I got NullPointer exception in first row (String hu = iit.getCentre().getIds().toString();) anyway :(
Also other suggestions failed, I am doing wrong something :)

Comment: Why are you doing toString() when you know getIds might return null?  First check with `if` if `getIds()` return null then act accordingly. `if( iit.getCentre().getIds()==null) {hu = ...} else {...}`

Comment: yes, also the problem was iit.getCentre(). could be null, now it`s fixed. Everything works correctly, thank you very much Joakim and have a good day :)